# Need advice designing a system that can horizontally scale a "request executor" scheduler

Tags: architecture, scheduled-tasks, scheduler, autoscaling, horizontal-scaling

I need some advice to design a system. Basically it consists of a webapp where people can schedule HTTP requests to be executed periodically. I have added a simple diagram here with the system design that I have imagined. The requests can be scheduled to run for example every minute, every 5 minutes, every hour, once a day, etc.

1. Frontend Webapp will send the data about the request to be executed to the Backend Webapp (including the periodicity).
2. Backend webapp receives this data, validates it and stores it on a SQL(?) database.
3. Request loader will scan the database and issue the request to be executed at the right time to the Request Executor, through a messaging system (NATS, Amazon SQS, Rabbit,...?!)
4. Request Executor simply picks the data from the queue and executes it, sending the result to Post Request Executor.

I have serious doubts about step 3 (Request Loader) and mainly how could it scale. I'm thinking in running this on Kubernetes. How could I horizontally scale this component without it "duplicating" the reads from the database? And I also have a concern if this "scanning" mechanism on the database is a good one.

I'm open to any suggestions, critics or alternatives. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: @DanielFarrell The general consensus is that design questionss are not reviewable on CR unless they accompany code - thus in the current form this post would not be on-topic there. See ["Which Site?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/341145) and ["Code Review or not?"](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114)

Comment: I will redact that comment... so,  there is no software  architecture site?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's anything wrong with your architecture.  How well it scales will likely be limited by how well you design the database schema and the request loader (as you said).

You mentioned SQS, so let me give you a more AWS Centric arch you might find interesting.

```
Frontend SPA -> API API Gateway + Lambda(s) -> DynamoDB --------|
                                    |                           |
                                    --> EventBridge             |
                                         |                      |
                        Check Lambda <---|----------------------|
```

In this picture, scheduling of the events is delegated to Event Bridge.
For [$1 per million requests](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/pricing/), you can [have event bridge execute a lambda  with a cron-like schedule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-create-rule-schedule.html).  The event can contain user defined data - in your case, probably the ID of the check to be performed.

Note that you're paying per *event* here, but you're *not* paying anything - in design, development, *or* operations - to handle scheduling and firing those events.  Even if your time is worth nothing, you probably can't come close to matching the price per event with your own system and still have anything like the high scale and availability of event bridge.

One caveat of event bridge is that its lowest resolution is 1 minute.  This is probably fine for your use case.  If you wanted more accuracy, you can add a sub-minute delay to an SQS Queue and have that trigger the same lambda with [SQS -> lambda integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html).

You can schedule these events as part of the handling of the incoming user request.  The rest of the information would probably go into a data store, say DynamoDB [($1.5/M Writes, $.25/M Reads)](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/on-demand/).

API Gateway ($3.5/M Requests) can be throttled to make sure you can control your costs. It also integrates with authentication to handle access control. AWS can provide free certs to their WAF which can front your API with your custom domain name.

AWS Lambda (about $.02 / M Requests, plus processing time) would be where your code executed.

The reason I think this architecture might be interesting to consider, is because it drives operational cost per request to the minimum while scaling indefinitely.  Paying $1/mo for a service like this is nice, but paying $1000/mo is fine... *if* the income from your site's usage justifies that scale.  And it will cost you basically nothing to scale on the human side - maybe adjust some limits and reduce logging volume to control costs.  Compare this to kubernetes:  getting a dev environment is easy, but getting a scalable, reliable prod environment in k8s is quite a stretch.  For one application, kubernetes is like using a blowtorch to light a cigarette.  Now, if you want to light a whole carton of cigarettes at once ... but you're not doing that here.  You have web requests, scheduled events, and result delivery.

You don't need a VPC or any network components for this either.  I would feel comfortable operating this on VPC-less Lambdas, and all the AWS APIs like Dynamo are public anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I need to investigate a bit on Lambdas. To be honest I don't know much about them. In your vision the lambdas would replace my "Request" components or also the Backend webapp?

Comment: They're candidates for both.  Lambdas tend to cost more per cpu-mb-second , so to speak, than EC2, but you pay by the 0.1 second increments, and you don't have to pay for spin up or spin down time, so whether an EC2 fleet or lambdas ends up being cheaper isn't a super simple equation.  Put an SQS Queue in the middle of event bridge and your code, and you can do both.  Really the core of this architecture is the suggestion that using Event Bridge to do your scheduling - with or without lambda - simplifies your architecture significantly and removes all non-event-driven components on your end.

Comment: Well I was checking Event Bridge as it sounded really cool for my use case. The downside is not actually the 1 minute limitation but the fact that I can only schedule events on the default bus. So basically I can't create separate buses and put a schedule on each one. I would need to put a schedule of every minute on the default bus and send all the events there. Not sure if this is a thing I want to implement, need to evaluate.

Comment: I don't see why you need different busses.  Each check schdule can correspond to a unique scheduled event, can't it?